# bootstrap menu stopped dropping, css missing?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I had a developer do some coding on a test site 5quote.com and for reason the bootstrap menu just does not want to drop on hover anymore whereas it did before. I have scoured the site and found some references, including this one by brbcoding:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
```

}

I applied this to the bootstrap css and it did work but the spacing is all to pot and also the menu still doesn't work when resizing the browser. I would appreciate it if someone more knowledgeable could take a look and come up with the css that's missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-nav > li:hover > .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
}
```

Use the above css code.This should solve the dropdown menu problem.
The menu won't possible work when resized as javascript required to initiate call for the css class is missing currently.

Comment: Thank for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately your css didn't affect the menu and the drop down still doesn't work